# java script how to access function within the same module when this doesn't point to the module instead points to the global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, this

When calling a function in the module in this way

```
app.get("/api/sessions/oauth/google", (req, res) => {
  return google_callback.googleOAuthHandler(req, res);
});
```

`this` points to the module and another function in the module can be accessed using `this`

```
googleOAuthHandler : async function (req, res) {
  const code = req.query.code.toString();
  const {id_token, access_token} = await this.getGoogleOAuthToken(code);
}
```

However passing the function as a parameter changes `this` to global and `this.getGoogleOAuthToken` becomes undefined
i.e when doing

```
app.get("/api/sessions/oauth/google", google_callback.googleOAuthHandler);
```

how would i access `getGoogleOAuthToken` in `googleOAuthHandler` in `google_callback` module when using this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get("/api/sessions/oauth/google", google_callback.googleOAuthHandler);
```

When passing function this way `this` doesn't mean the `module`. So `this.getGoogleOAuthToken` doesn't work.

however we can use `module.exports.getGoogleOAuthToken` to access the function within the same module. Using `module.exports.getGoogleOAuthToken` also works in the first example.

Alternatively if you don't like `module.exports` to call the function you can place line `const _this = this;` at the top of the file or `const _this = module.exports = { ... }` and use `_this.function` to call a function inside the module.

Also just noticed that in the first example `this.function` only works because i'm using this syntax.

```
module.exports = {
  func1 : function(){},
  func2 : function(){}
}
```

when exporting with

```
module.exports.func1 = function(){}
module.exports.func2 = function(){}
```

`this` cannot be used to access the other function